# AWS AppSync error after "amplify push", Value for field '$[lastSync]' must be a number

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-appsync

Hi im using amplify dynamodb table and at for client side using DataStore AppSync. After performing amplify push command, im getting this error in graphql SyncTable call of DataStore.

[image]
Value for field '$[lastSync]' must be a number

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem. After some investigation I found there is a bug in [Amplify generated resolvers](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/custom-business-logic/#override-amplify-generated-resolvers).

In line 103 of every **"Query.syncXXXX.preAuth.1.req.vtl"** generated by amplify (which you may find under /amplify/backend/api/[your project name]/build/resolvers)

```
## [Start]  Set query expression for @key **
#if( !$scan )
  #set( $limit = $util.defaultIfNull($context.args.limit, 100) )
  #set( $QueryRequest = {
  "version": "2018-05-29",
  "operation": "Sync",
  "limit": $limit,
  "lastSync": $util.toJson($util.defaultIfNull($ctx.args.lastSync, null)),
  "query": $modelQueryExpression
} )
```

The "lastSync" field is filled with string typed value because of the unnecessary call of "$util.toJson". This is the exact cause of your error message "$[lastSync] must be a number"

A workaround to the problem is to change:

```
"lastSync": $util.toJson($util.defaultIfNull($ctx.args.lastSync, null)),
```

into

```
"lastSync": $util.defaultIfNull($ctx.args.lastSync, null),
```

and then override the generated resolver

see [Override Amplify-generated resolvers](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/custom-business-logic/#override-amplify-generated-resolvers)